# Sending Error Mails when using django-sentry not working

Tags: django, error-handling, sentry

I am using django-sentry for logging errors. I also want to enable throttled error mails to be sent to admins whenever an error occurs. But I can not get it working.

a) Normal django error mailing is working.
b) but on removing ADMINS and adding SENTRY_ADMINS(like below) it stops working:

```
   DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

SENTRY_TESTING = True

ADMINS = ()
SENTRY_ADMINS = ('my.name@domain.com',)

MANAGERS = ADMINS



MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'sentry.client.middleware.SentryResponseErrorIdMiddleware',
....
)

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'name@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Though entries are correctly being made and shown in panel. I mark all errors as resolved before testing(to satisfy throttle condition of sentry) but it is still not working.

Can anyone point to what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Should you not leave the ADMINS as it is?

Comment: That is like normal case, error-mail whenever error occurs,but does not enable "throttled emails" feature in sentry - mail only when first time error is seen or when first time error is seen again after being resolved.  http://readthedocs.org/docs/sentry/en/latest/config.html#other-settings

Answer (score 4):

Jiaaro is almost correct. The From address used by Sentry (and Django itself) is defined by settings.SERVER_EMAIL. It will use the SENTRY_ADMINS addresses only to send email *to*.

So setting `SERVER_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER` should fix this.

Comment: @AjayYadav did this fix your problem? If so, please accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are trying to use gmail to send the messages but you are trying to send the messages from "my.name@domain.com"

As far as I know, gmail does not allow you to send messages from email addresses which you are not a verified as owning (in gmail).

Try setting your SENTRY_ADMINS to...

```
SENTRY_ADMINS = (
  "YOUR_GMAIL_ADDRESS@gmail.com",
)
```